# What class is the return object for facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getSession()?

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs

When attempting to the get the Session in SSJS on an XPage ([as explained here](http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=get-sessionid-in-ssjs)), the type ahead will only go as far as `getSession()`.

I can see the `getSession()` call returns a standard `java.lang.Object`, which explains why the type ahead beyond `getSession()` only shows the props/methods for the `java.lang.Object` class.

However if you continue and call the `getId()` method, as detailed in the link above, then you can save the XPage and it will run without a problem.

That's fine, but what if I want to make the same call in Java, the code won't compile because, as mentioned above for SSJS, the returned object is a standard `java.lang.Object` and doesn't have a method called `getId()`.

Therefore can I cast the returned object to allow me to access the session methods? If so, what class should I cast it to?

Comment: I'd start with [HttpSession](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code `facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getSession()` returns the class `com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.servlet.LCDAdapterHttpSession`.

If you need to know what class the object belongs to simply add `.getClass().getName()` to it. So the code in your case would be -  `facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getSession().getClass().getName()`

In Java you would have to write

```
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
// import com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.servlet.LCDAdapterHttpSession;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
...
...
// LCDAdapterHttpSession s = (LCDAdapterHttpSession)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
HttpSession s = (HttpSession)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
return s.getId();
```

The class `LCDAdapterHttpSession` implements `javax.servlet.http.HttpSession`.

Comment: Thanks Naveen. So the issue is, in Java, 'getSession(boolean)' returns java.lang.Object which doesn't allow me access to the session's methods ('getId()' etc). So my question is, what class do I need to cast the return object to? The class and package you mention (com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino) doesn't appear to be available when using Java design elements.

Comment: @lee_mcmullen: Updated my answer to include code snippet. Also try to put the code `facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getSession().getClass().getName()` in a computed field to see which class it prints.

Comment: I think it's important to emphasize that for you as developer does not matter what the actual implementation is (`LCDAdapterHttpSession`), you should cast to `javax.servlet.http.HttpSession`.